# Failed to open rtlsdr device #0

Tags: java

We have the task to use some piece of hardware to analyse the signals send by a glider plane, like ADSB or ELT.
For this we decided to use the following hardwarestick:

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.de/Salcar%C2%AE-FM-Radio-Digitalradio-Empf%C3%A4nger-RTL2832U/dp/B00FVGOMIO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1429783947&sr=8-1&keywords=RTL+Stick">link</a>
```

We want to use the `rtl_tcp` tool to get the information to the program.
My problem is that I always get this message:

```
C:\MyProject\rtlsdr\x64>rtl_test

Found 1 device(s):   
  0:  Generic RTL2832U (e.g. hama nano)  

Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U (e.g. hama nano)  
Failed to open rtlsdr device #0.
```

does anyone know what the problem could be? i tryed reinstalling the driver over zadig multiple times, without success.

the driver i choose was: `WinUSB (v6.1.7600.16385)`

Comment: My guess is permissions related.  Are you running as administrator?  I've fought USB devices with Windows before myself and have had one where even as administrator I always got permission errors on connect...

Comment: hmmm might be, the driver says Install successfull

Comment: how did you fixed the issue?